# Filter array keys starting with certain characters

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

```
$persons = [
   'name_1' => 'asfddf',
   'name_2' => 'gsdg',
   'name_3' => '23423',
   'name_aaa' => '123sdg',
   'test' => '123sdg',
   'other' => '123sdg',
   'name_5' => 'sdg2334',
];
```

How to get values from this array which in key have `name` ?

In my example I would like receive:

```
$persons = [
   'name_1' => 'asfddf',
   'name_2' => 'gsdg',
   'name_3' => '23423',
   'name_aaa' => '123sdg',
   'name_5' => 'sdg2334',
];
```

I can use `foreach` and check key by `strpos`, but maybe is better way for this? Any map reduce?

Comment: `foreach` is the simplest and the most readable way. Why are you trying to complicate things?

Comment: you could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` and a callback if you want, but in the end it is the same as iterating the array with a `foreach`.

Comment: @xander but note that `array_filter` uses __keys__ in callback since php5.6, so it won't work with older versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution for PHP 5.6 & above:**

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag:

```
$array = array_filter($persons, function($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'name') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r($array);
```

---

**Solution for older versions:**

This uses key for comparison and then applies key intersection using [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key)

```
$array = array_filter(array_keys($persons), function($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'name') === 0;
});

print_r(array_intersect_key($persons, array_flip($array)));
```

---

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [name_1] => asfddf
    [name_2] => gsdg
    [name_3] => 23423
    [name_aaa] => 123sdg
    [name_5] => sdg2334
)
```

Comment: Note that __third__ argument added in php5.6.

Comment: @u_mulder Added alternative solution as well!

Answer (score 0):

well you can try this with `substr`

```
foreach($persons as $key => $value){
    if("name_" == substr($key,0,5)){
    // process the value
     }
 }
```

Or you can simply do this using `preg_match`

```
foreach($persons as $key => $value){
    if (preg_match('/name_/',$key)) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```